# Python arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python

I'm using Pycharm to study Deep Learning. Yesterday I installed Pycharm and Tensorflow 2.1.0.
Then I just type code from a book that I studied, and this error occurred.
By Googling, I know the problem is that array must use integer not float.
But in Jupyter Notebook, it doesn't occur. I don't know how to fix it..

What should I do? Please Help me..

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
import numpy as np

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words = 10000)
print(max([max(sequence) for sequence in train_data]))

def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension = 10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension), dtype=np.int32)
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequences] = 1
return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)
```

and Traceback..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/ge971/PycharmProjects/Tensorflow_Example/keras.py", line 15, in <module>
    x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
 File "C:/Users/ge971/PycharmProjects/Tensorflow_Example/keras.py", line 12, in vectorize_sequences
    results[i, sequences] = 1
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Comment: What's the output when you execute `print(sequences)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
i1 = np.array([1, 1, 1])  # int values
r1 = a[i1]  # This works and gives [2, 2, 2]

i2 = np.array([1.1, 1.1, 1.1])  # float values
r2 = a[i2]  # This doesn't work
```

You cannot use `float` values to index an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension = 10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension), dtype=np.int32)
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequences] = 1  # <---- This line to results[i, sequence]
    return results
```